# Is X11 required for adding text overlay?

Tags: mlt

I'm trying to run the below command in a script and it seems it's not adding any text layout to the video, I'm sure I didn't it before and it was fine.

My question is, do I need to set up X11 environment in order to use dynamictext or text filters?

Thanks in advance.

```
/usr/bin/melt \
"/var/www/html/test/nkLcBPkebo/t-1.mp4" \
-audio-track \
"/var/www/html/test/nkLcBPkebo/t-1_sound.mp4" \
-attach-track \
"text:This is my best video" \
-0 \
in=0 out=0 fgcolour="#004fed" bgcolour=0 olcolour="#fff200" outline=3 pad="50x0" size=80 weight=700 style="italic" halign="center" valign="top" family="Ubuntu" \
-profile hdv_720_25p -progress \
-consumer avformat:"/var/www/html/test/nkLcBPkebo/1.mp4" \
vcodec="libx264" vb="5000k" acodec="aac" ab="128k" frequency=44100 deinterlace=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the issue! it's was all about the order of the parameters :)

Having the text right after the video (before the audio) should fix it

```
/usr/bin/melt \
"/var/www/html/test/nkLcBPkebo/t-1.mp4" \

-attach-track \
"text:This is my best video" \
-0 \
in=0 out=0 fgcolour="#004fed" bgcolour=0 olcolour="#fff200" outline=3     pad="50x0" size=80 weight=700 style="italic" halign="center" valign="top"     family="Ubuntu" \

-audio-track \
"/var/www/html/test/nkLcBPkebo/t-1_sound.mp4" \
-profile hdv_720_25p -progress \
-consumer avformat:"/var/www/html/test/nkLcBPkebo/1.mp4" \
vcodec="libx264" vb="5000k" acodec="aac" ab="128k" frequency=44100     deinterlace=1
```